# Deployment of smart contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain

How to deploy a smart contract on my own blokchain network?
I have created using python and running on postman client server interface.
I have already tested on ganache , solidity IDE and ethfiddle.

Comment: Well Ganache *is* your own blockchain network

Comment: That I know. I have created my own chain like you can mine block on it,get chain function with all  node

Comment: I want to upload on that chain server.

Comment: use truffle, web3, or ethers